# Exploitable URLs list

Tags: exploit, url

I have a web application which has recently been deployed to AWS.

In the last days, i got random requests to *admin* urls, like */admin.php*, *wp-admin.php* etc. (obvious they are trying to find exploitable sections)

I want to create a blacklist of IPs accessing those urls.

Is there a list of exploitable URLs, so i capture all the IP addresses trying to access them?

I have searched on google a lot, and i could't find anything too useful.

Comment: Use caution blacklisting IPs, remember many ISPs assign short term leases for public IPs, the owner of that IP is the attacker one day and a genuine visitor another, You may also end up banning thousands of users for large organisations who use NAT (eg a university)

Comment: Are you using Wordpress? If so, you should use Wordfence which does all this for you.

Comment: I am not using wordpress. Hackers have a list of exploitable admin pages. I don't necessarily want to ban the IP forever, but at least i need to capture it and take further actions. (the project manager wants to capture these IP addresses)

Comment: You could try logging IP/URL's for 404's. Then after N days skim through those manually for anything that is clearly not just user error. Maybe add a limited time block - seconds to say maybe 24 hours - to anyone that requests those URLs in future. This means after the first failed attempt their scan will likely fail.

Comment: You might also want to look at something like FailToBan or placing your site behind a service like cloudflare.

Comment: Your question is more nebulous than you expect. You are not looking for *exploitable* URL paths, you are looking for common admin page URLs. If you want to know the *exploitable* URLs, that's a massive undertaking. Frankly, I'd mine your logs for invalid requests and build your list from that.

Comment: why slow down your users to prevent a few harmless requests?

Comment: Thank you all for answers! i found a list of "exploitable" urls here
https://www.hackthissite.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=7704

It is also a good aproach to capture all the 404 errors and make the list on the fly, but our services reutrns 404 in different use-cases as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried Fail2Ban? One of it's preconfigured filters for Apache is designed to "match web requests for selected URLs that don't exist", and will let you ban offending addresses accordingly.

If memory serves you can customize the bans to expire after a specific amount of time, and kick in after a specific number of violations, so you could set it to block any ip that tries to access /admin.php for 3 days, drastically reducing the viability of random scans while not permanently blocking an IP that might soon belong to a legitimate visitor.

How-to's [here](http://xmodulo.com/configure-fail2ban-apache-http-server.html) or [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-an-apache-server-with-fail2ban-on-ubuntu-14-04#adjusting-the-general-settings-within-fail2ban) to help you get started.

The filter I believe you're looking for is called apache-botsearch.conf on my system.